# Have no output as html view

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an `XML` file which reads a relates `XSLT` file and then I could see output as `HTML` in web browser. There should be table where the first column is the name of components' node in XML file and the second column is the description of components
But after some changes I could not have any desired output. It shows only an empty table as is shown in following pic.

[image]

Would you please help me?

My `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<Summary>
    <test name="test">
        <xml_name name="ABC">
            <version num="104">
                <component name="APPS">
                    <componenet_ver>104</componenet_ver>
                </component>
            <component name="Ner">
                <componenet_ver>1.0</componenet_ver>
                </component>
                <component name="HUNE">
                    <componenet_ver>003</componenet_ver>
                </component>
                <component name="FADA">
                    <componenet_ver>107</componenet_ver>
                </component>
                <component name="VEDA">
                    <componenet_ver>8.8</componenet_ver>
                </component>
            </version>
        </xml_name>
    </test>
</Summary>
```

and `XSLT` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Summary/test">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr bgcolor="Peru">
                    <th>Components</th>
                    <th>Versions</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//component">
                    <xsl:variable name="CompomName" select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="VerName" select="description"/>
                    <tr>
                       <td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$CompomName}"> </td>
                       <td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$VerName}"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>                                 
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <tr> not closing, `<xsl:for-each>` not closing

Comment: Sorry for the missing end Tags. I have edited the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet is not well-formed: you are missing the closing tags for the second `<tr>` as well as for the `<xsl:for-each>` and `</xsl:stylesheet>` instructions.

---

### Added:

> It shows only an empty table.

The table is empty because the table cells have no content (other than spaces). Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Summary/test">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr bgcolor="Peru">
                    <th>Components</th>
                    <th>Versions</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//component">
                    <xsl:variable name="CompomName" select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="VerName" select="componenet_ver"/>
                    <tr>
                       <td bgcolor="aqua" name="{$CompomName}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$CompomName"/>
                       </td>
                       <td bgcolor="aqua" name="{$VerName}"> 
                            <xsl:value-of select="$VerName"/>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>                                 
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not sure if you really need to name the cells, I have left that in.

Note that your `<xsl:variable name="VerName" select="description"/>` does not select anything.

Comment: Of course, sorry for missing end tags. I have edited my question and still remains problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (corrected missing end tags):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Summary/test">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr bgcolor="Peru">
                    <th>Components</th>
                    <th>Versions</th>
                    </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//component">
                        <xsl:variable name="CompomName" select="@name"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="VerName" select="./componenet_ver"/>
                    <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$CompomName}"><xsl:value-of select="$CompomName"/></td>
                    <td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$VerName}"><xsl:value-of select="$VerName"/></td>  
</tr>                                 
</xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Royeh, What is your question? I tried your XML together with the corrected XSLT and got a result...

Comment: @Royeh, this is empty because your XSLT does not set any value between the td-tags: `<td>Value must go here</td>`

Comment: would you please explain it a bit more or send as an answer.

Comment: @Royeh, look at my edits: I changed your variable "VerName". You'll find the content of "CompomName" and "VerName" between the td-tags.

Answer (score 0):

couple of corrections:

1/ You need to write values as text of  elements which are missing.

Corrected:

```
<td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$CompomName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$CompomName" />
</td>
<td bgcolor="aqua" name = "{$VerName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$VerName" /> 
</td>
```

2/ for variable VerName, you are selecting "description" element which does not exist. What you might be intending is to select "component_ver" element as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="VerName" select="componenet_ver"/>
```

Try these 2 and it would work.

[image]

Comment: Why are you repeating existing answers?